# Why I can't access self.<method> while inside pdb

Tags: python, scope, pdb

Consider a code snippet like this:

```
class ABC:
    def method1(self, word):
             ...

    def method2(self):
        str_list = ['this', 'is', 'a', 'list', 'of', 'strings']
        pdb.set_trace()
        str_list = [self.method1(word) for word in str_list] ...(1)

obj = ABC()
obj.method2()
```

At the break point, when I copy-paste the command `(1)` in the pdb debugger shell, it fails to execute the command and rather gives me the error:

```
*** NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Can anyone help me understand this behavior - is it something related to the scope of list comprehensions and class objects?

---

```
PS C:\fooProjects> & C:/Python38/python.exe c:/fooProjects/tmp.py
> c:\fooprojects\tmp.py(38)method2()
-> str_list = [self.method1(word) for word in str_list]
(Pdb) [self.method1(word) for word in str_list]
*** NameError: name 'self' is not defined
(Pdb)
```

Comment: You [just asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65458294/why-i-cant-access-self-method-while-inside-pdb) literally this exact question, word for word.

Comment: And no, that's still not the error message that list comprehension would give you.

Comment: Please provide more details, as I wasn't able to reproduce your error - it worked for me. Did you copy-paste the whole line: `str_list = [self.method1(word) for word in str_list]` in the pdb debugger shell ?

Comment: Edited the question, ```self``` is not defined

Comment: @BeniaminH, added the complete snippet. I am able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: Ideally - paste here whole output and input from your console, starting from `python your_file.py`

Comment: Can reproduce by pasting **just** the list comprehension into the PDB *prompt. added aPDB  *trace* to question.

Comment: Strange, take a look on my output: https://pastebin.pl/view/c1dbe2a6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a list comprehension, everything but the expression for the outermost iterable runs in a new scope. Code you enter at a PDB prompt is executed with `exec`, and new scopes created inside `exec` can't access closure variables, which `self` would be.

Instead of list comprehensions, using the `interact` command and writing a regular `for` loop will avoid this scoping issue. However, `interact` creates its own new namespace, and variable assignments executed inside that namespace won't propagate back to the original namespace, so if you want to assign your new list to `str_list`, you'd have to run `str_list = []` *before* `interact` and then add stuff to the list in `interact`.

Comment: Is it somehow environment dependent ? https://pastebin.pl/view/c467e68d - `self` is accessible from my pdb prompt.

Comment: It appears that it depends on python version, not the way you import it. In python3 it is as @user2357112 wrote, in python2 `self` is accessible.